# Domain of a Standard Parabola

Tags: functions

I was just wondering if it would be applicable to write the domain of a parabola is:

-∞ < x < ∞

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A parabola like $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c, \ a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ can take in any value for $x$.

Comment: Is it possible to put it in the form -∞ < x < ∞ ?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: If I was to express the domain of y=x^2 could I write it as - ∞<x< ∞

Comment: Yes. That's fine. If you are satisfied, could you upvote/accept my answer?

Comment: I disagree.  The domain is a set.  Therefore, you should write $\{x \mid -\infty < x < \infty\}$ or $(-\infty, \infty)$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Well when you say '{x∣−∞ < x < ∞}' I can instead write 'Domain: −∞ < x < ∞'