# Domain of a Standard Parabola: $y = x^2$

Tags: functions

For the domain of a standard parabola, we would write, in bracket notation: $(-\infty, \infty)$.

So, I was wondering if you could also write the domain of a parabola as $-\infty < x < \infty$.

Likewise the domain of a function $f(x)$ could be, in bracket notation: $(4,2)$. This is the equivalent of $4 < x < 2$.

So can you write the domain of a parabola as $-\infty < x < \infty$?

Comment: Note the definition $$(a,b)=\{x: a<x<b\}$$

Comment: Well, if you want to be specific, the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$ is the *set* of all numbers $x$ such that $-\infty < x<\infty$, i.e. $(-\infty, \infty)=\{x:-\infty < x <\infty\}$. Of course we could generalise this for any bounds $a$ and $b$ for $(a,b)$. If you only assert that $-\infty < x < \infty$ then, equivalently, you are implying that $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$. Note, by definition, that $(-\infty, \infty)=: \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes. You could write it as x is an element of the reals, but, do you find it inappropriate to write it in the form −∞ < x < ∞ in any way?

Comment: Please do not ask the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3570762/domain-of-a-standard-parabola) twice.  Instead, edit the original question to clarify what you need.

Comment: Also, note that $(4, 2) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 4 < x < 2\} = \emptyset$ since no real number is both greater than $4$ and less than $2$.